# Variable change detection does not seem to be working with ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

I have already tried things in posts similar to mine, but still can't seem to get this working. I want to show something on my webpage after about 15 seconds. I use `setTimout` and then an `if` statment to check if something is true or not and then change a Boolean variable accordingly.

I have a component that has a variable `timer` which I originally set to `false`. Then I run the the `setTimeout` in a function. After 15 seconds I make a check. I then change the `timer` variable, if needed. This did not work. So then I also added a `router.navigate` back to my page thinking it would reevaluate the `timer` variable, but this also did not work.

This is my `html`

```
<br> <br>
<div *ngIf="timer == false">
  <p>Results are loading. Please wait.</p>
  <div>
  <div *ngIf="timer == true">
    <p>Sorry, but this seems to be taking longer than usual. Please wait while we continue to check.</p>
    </div>
 <br>
 <div class="spinner">
  <div class="bounce1"></div>
  <div class="bounce2"></div>
  <div class="bounce3"></div>

</div>
```

Then inside my `component`

```
constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router, private _dataService: DataService)
    {}
    public timer: boolean = false;

checkDuplicates(someArray){
        var count = 0;
        var i = 0;
        var length = this.userResults.length;

        setTimeout(() => {
                    if(length != someArray.length){
                        this.timer = true;
                        this.router.navigate(['/processing'])
                        console.log('turn on new processing notification')
                    }

                }, 15000)
```

As of now I am getting the "Results are loading. Please wait.", but even when the timer variable is switched to `true` no change. I tried this with and without the router.navigate. I have tried all of the things listed below with now luck. I have also tried doing a manual update by doing `ChangeDetectionRef` and `NgZone` and `ApplicationRef` methods mentioned in other posts. Could I please get some insight.

Comment: Try replacing `timer == false` with `!timer` and `timer == true` with `timer`

Comment: This still did not work. @PrerakSola

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you have bad HTML above. You aren't closing your first ngIf properly, you have <div> instead of </div>

Comment: thank you for catching that. Surprised I did not get an error when trying to compile. It did not fix my issue though

Comment: Did you import the `CommonModule` ?

Comment: Are you ever changing the length of `this.userResults.length` or `someArray.length`?  Are you seeing the "turn on new processing notification" message in the console log?

Comment: yes I have it imported.

Comment: I change this.uerResults.length in a function that is called later. Wouldn't this still work? It wont actually perform the if until after the 15 seconds have passed, correct? I do see the message in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this working using `ngIf`. Instead I formatted the html to have an `id` tab and then I used `document.getElementById` and changed it in the `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <br> <br>
    <div *ngIf="!timer">
      <p>Results are loading. Please wait.</p>
      <div>
      <div *ngIf="timer">
        <p>Sorry, but this seems to be taking longer than usual. Please wait while we continue to check.</p>
        </div>
     <br>
     <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bounce1"></div>

  <div class="bounce2"></div>
  <div class="bounce3"></div>

</div>

constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router, private _dataService: DataService)
    {}
    timer=false;

checkDuplicates(someArray){
let _self= this;
        var count = 0;
        var i = 0;
        var length = this.userResults.length;

        setTimeout(() => {
                    if(length != someArray.length){
                        _self.timer = true;
                        this.router.navigate(['/processing'])
                        console.log('turn on new processing notification')
                    }
                    else{
                        _self.timer = false;
                    }
                }, 15000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: This did not work either. I get the message printing in my console, but no change in the html